# Python xgb.cv use multiple evalation metrics

Tags: python, machine-learning, cross-validation, xgboost, metrics

I am currently trying to find the optimal parameters of a XGBoost model.
After finding the optimal parameters I would like to evaluate the model with cross validation by using multiple customized evalation metrics.

Let's assume I would like to use the following two metrics:
(I would like to use different metrics, but the first one was provided in the documentation and I just want to get to know how I can use tow metrics)

```
def rmsle(predt: np.ndarray, dtrain: xgb.DMatrix) -> Tuple[str, float]:
    ''' Root mean squared log error metric.'''
    y = dtrain.get_label()
    predt[predt < -1] = -1 + 1e-6
    elements = np.power(np.log1p(y) - np.log1p(predt), 2)
    return 'PyRMSLE', float(np.sqrt(np.sum(elements) / len(y)))

def rmsle2(predt: np.ndarray, dtrain: xgb.DMatrix) -> Tuple[str, float]:
    ''' Root mean squared log error metric.'''
    y = dtrain.get_label()
    predt[predt < -1] = -1 + 1e-6
    elements = np.power(np.log1p(y) - np.log1p(predt), 2)
    return 'PyRMSLE', float(2*np.sqrt(np.sum(elements) / len(y)))
```

Now I use the follwing line to compute the models:

```
cvresult = xgb.cv(xgb_param, xgtrain, num_boost_round=alg.get_params()['n_estimators'], folds=cv,
    feval={rmsle,rmsle2}, early_stopping_rounds=early_stopping_rounds)
```

Unfortunately this is not working.
If I only use on feval metric `feval=rmsle`, this works out.

I can use two 'standard metrics' like the RMSE or MAE:

```
 cvresult = xgb.cv(xgb_param, xgtrain, num_boost_round=alg.get_params()['n_estimators'], folds=cv,
        metrics={'mae','rmse'}, early_stopping_rounds=early_stopping_rounds)
```

Here no error appears, but when I want to use more custom metrics, I get an error.

It would be amazing if anyone could provide me some help here.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I did it just with:

```
cross_validate(xgb1, X, y, scoring=scorer, cv=KFold(n_splits=cv_folds, random_state=seed, shuffle=True), verbose = 0)
```

and

```
scorer = {'MAE': make_scorer(MAE, greater_is_better=False),
         'MAPE': make_scorer(MAPE, greater_is_better=False),
         'MdAE': make_scorer(MdAE, greater_is_better=False),
         'MdAPE': make_scorer(MdAPE, greater_is_better=False),
         'In_10': make_scorer(In_10, greater_is_better=True),
         'In_20': make_scorer(In_20, greater_is_better=True)}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.training), feval argument is an evaluation function that is used to score your model and there should be just one of those in your `.cv` method. However, you can evaluate your CV by using `metrics` as you already did, but according to [this](https://discuss.xgboost.ai/t/multiple-evaluation-metrics-in-xgboost-python-native/609), it looks like your dict might be missing a key-value pairs. Try to define it as following:

```py
 cvresult = xgb.cv(xgb_param, xgtrain, num_boost_round=alg.get_params()['n_estimators'], folds=cv,
        metrics={'first_score': rmsle, 'second_score': rmsle2}, early_stopping_rounds=early_stopping_rounds)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately it does not work this way. In the end I did it just with: cross_validate